# How to map field values from Source to only null/empty fields values of Destination Object?

Tags: java, spring

Let's say there are two classes Foo and Bar:

```
class Foo {

public Foo(int fooId, String name, int age) {
    this.fooId = fooId;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

private int fooId;
private String name;
private int age;

//Getters, Setters, toString
```

}

```
class Bar {

public Bar(int fooId, String name, int age) {
    this.fooId = fooId;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

private int fooId;
private String name;
private int age;

//Getters, Setters, toString
```

}

```
public class Mapper {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    Foo foo = new Foo(1, "ABC", 30);            
    Bar bar = new Bar(2, null, 25);
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.map(foo, bar);      
    System.out.println(bar.toString());

}
```

}

Actual Result : Bar [fooId=1, name=ABC, age=30]

Expected Result : Bar [fooId=2, name=ABC, age=25]

ModelMapper can help to map the values but overrides all of destination values as well.
But, I want to map values from class Foo to Bar, but only for the null value without replacing the non-null values of destination. In this case, only `name` which is null.

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand what you try to do here, and seems your sample code is little bit wrong and I am 100% does not work, you cannot assign String value to Integer object.  Is this ModelMapper class something you coded or is an existing class from some java library?  can you add more details of the ModelMapper class maybe library name and version?

Comment: I hope it makes clear now

Comment: will this works for you modelMapper.getConfiguration().setSkipNullEnabled(true);

Comment: this will skip the null values from source, so does not work. I want to replace only the null/empty values of the destination object.

Comment: Not sure if you checked the JavaDoc of ModelMapper class to see if supports your use case (http://modelmapper.org/javadoc/), at first glance, ModelMapper.map() does not support what you are trying to achieve, you may end up creating your own Converter, or extending PropertyMap class and define your own mapping rules.